# Is it possible to skip itteration in java, when you are using method in that loop?

Tags: java

Is it possible to skip itteration in java, when you are using method in that loop?

For example:

```
Method(String name){
  if(name==5){
     //Do something to skip itteration
  }
}

public main(){
   for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
     method(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried using continue, break but it doesnt work.

Comment: Why can't you just put everything you wanna run in the else clause

Comment: Restructure your code, put the condition in the loop... By the way, that condition is likely to cause problems, `name` is a `String` but you (1) compare it with `==` instead of `equals()` and (2) `5` is an `int`...

Comment: Its an example. Practical method is static and in another class.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use the keyword `continue` for this purpose.

```
int x = 5;
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
   continue;
}
```

But this is not a iteration. You are making a function call as it seems. Inside a function you could just call return.

```
Method(String name){
  if(name==5){
     return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the code below, the iteration will be skipped once the sampleMethod returns false;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(!sampleMethod(i)) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}

static boolean sampleMethod(int i) {
    if(i == 5) return false;

    return true;
}
```